# distribute iphone universal app

Tags: iphone

When you distribute an iphone/ipad universal app do you compile it against the 3.1.3 SDK or 3.2? When are some of the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just built an app with 3.1.2 that was just accepted into the app store.  Building with a lower version will ensure compatibility with people that are running older versions of the OS on their iphone/ipod touch.

EDIT: you should compile with 3.2...see my comment below.

Comment: does the same binary run on the iPad?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to compile with 3.2 for your app to be universal, i.e. for it to run on iPad as well.

Comment: Base SDK should be 3.2, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120/how-to-make-iphone-app-for-multiple-firmwares/3027213#3027213) for some more details about targeting different SDK versions.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it with SDK 3.2