# Upgrading to Xcode 3.2.3 and iPhone SDK 4

Tags: iphone, xcode

Now that this is out of beta I would like to upgrade. I currently have Xcode 3.2.2 installed along the w/ iPhone 3.0 SDKs (3.0, 3.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.2).

If I install Xcode 3.2.3 and iPhone SDK 4 will I still be able to build against the 3.0 SDKs by simply selecting it from the active SDK list?

Thanks!

Comment: With Xcode 3.2.3 you can build against the 4.0 SDK and target 3.0 devices.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can, to target older iPhone OS's with the new iOS 4 SDK (XCode 3.2.3), Select your XCode project -> Get Info, and then select "iPhone Device 4.0" as the Base SDK, and then select the lowest iPhone OS version from iPhone OS Deployment Target that you need to support (3.0).

Hope this helps!