# Howto develope and distribute for OS3.0 with iPhone running iOS4

Tags: iphone

i'm a little bit confused about the current iOS4 update.
I developed a little App, und wanted to do some improvment.
Today i updated my iPhone to iOS4.

When i use Xcode 3.2 i couldn't use my iPhone for testing, its not supported.

When i use Xcode 3.2.3 i can use my iPhone, but no testing with OS3.0.

What is the best way to make an App that is Running on os3 and iOS4?

Thanks in advance

Max

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max,

To target older iPhone OS's with the new iOS 4 SDK, Select your XCode project -> Get Info, and then select "iPhone Device 4.0" as the Base SDK, and then select the lowest iPhone OS version from iPhone OS Deployment Target that you need to support, such as 3.0.

If you have any code in your app that is specific to a version of the iPhone OS, you may have to put OS version checking code around those portions to get things to work properly. For example, playing a video from a URL in iOS3 is different now in iOS4 so I had to check the actual OS version on the device to decide which code to present to the user.

Hope this helps!