# iPhone OS Deployment Target after update to iPhone SDK 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I just updated to iPhone SDK 4 and am trying to debug on my device with 3.1.3 installed. Before the update, I compiled with Base and Active SDK set to 3.1.3 and all was well. *After* the update, I'm limited to SDKs 4.0 and 3.2--setting the base to 4.0 and iPhone OS Deployment Target to iPhone OS 3.1.3, I'm able to build and install on my 3.1.3 device, but receive the following error:

> Error from Debugger: mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack

I'm not using anything specific to the newer SDK, as I haven't touched a bit of code, just updated the SDK/XCode. So what am I doing incorrectly? The application runs as expected on an iOS4-installed device. Are there changes to pre-existing API's that need to be weakly linked perhaps? Thanks for all help.

Comment: So I ended up stripping everything down and starting from scratch, eventually just migrating everything into a new project and it worked as expected. It's a rather unfortunate solution as I have no idea what caused the above error. Thanks for everyone's help. If this is better as an answer to my own question, please advise, I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the app completely from your dev device, doing a build -> clean all targets, and then build again to your device?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer on macforums](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=780783).  If it's correct, then you probably have a memory corruption problem in your app that is confusing the debugger.  Perhaps over-releasing something somewhere.

This probably isn't related to the SDK you are compiling with.  It's possible you had this problem in your app all along but it just didn't show up until things moved around with the new Xcode, SDK, etc.

**EDIT** - I just ran into this problem myself trying to update an older app of mine to 4.0.  It would run fine in the simulator and would install and run on the device except it wouldn't run in the debugger on the device.  Anyway, I finally decided it was the .xcodeproj file that was corrupt or bad in some way and created a new project, copied over my source files to the new project and now it all works again.  It's a pain but it only took about 20 mins to duplicate all my settings and I spent a couple hours trying to get the debugger to work.

Comment: The error gets thrown before my app entry point. No breakpoints catch before the error and I'm new enough to this to not make any sense of stack at the time of error.

Answer (score -2):

Myself (and probably many others) are concerned about "will I still be able to compile/install apps for v3.1.3 of the iPhone OS?"

And what version of xCode does it become IMPOSSIBLE to ever write v3.1.3 apps again?
(Without installing a second copy of an older version of xCode.)

I've read the mile-long document that Apple wrote on the subject... but it sure would be simpler to understand if they just *LISTED* the various versions of each... instead of writing long paragraphs.

If you have:

- Mac OS version 10.x.x x
- xCode version x.x.x
- SDK version(s) x.x.x

you can produce apps for iPhone OS x.x.x through x.x.x?

Comment: @Janice: Questions should be posted as a new question, not as an answer.  This isn't a discussion style forum.  But your question is already [answered here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120/how-to-make-iphone-app-for-multiple-firmwares/3027213#3027213)

Comment: So I'm pretty much limited to 3.2+; I'd say that's reason for concern, considering I can easily target 3.0+ with an earlier SDK.

Comment: @progrmr: I would say my situation would indicate that the post you link to doesn't in fact answer Janice's point/question, as I'm not referencing any new APIs etc.

Comment: You're not limited to 3.2, you can target 2.0-4.0 with the Xcode 3.2.3 and SDK 4.0.  Janice's questions are not related to your problem.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a site that *DOES* actually allow things to be discussed and talked about?  (StackOverFlow has to be about the most UNFRIENDLY site I've ever seen in my lifetime.)  Who in their right mind would "forbid talking about things"???  Bye.

Comment: @Janice - We're not trying to be mean, it's just that this site is structured differently from a discussion forum.  The focus is on programming questions that have a definite answer, not open-ended discussion on issues.  There are plenty of sites out there that handle the latter, so there's no need for this one to take on that role as well.  If you have specific questions about a topic, we'd be glad to answer them.

Comment: I'd say "all" other sites are like that -- in particular forums, like http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/ -- SO is a little unique in that sense, but regardless, I don't think people are that unfriendly. They just expect you to do things in a certain order: questions are for questions, answers are for answers -- your "answer" should have been a comment or a separate question, not an answer. If people didn't care, SO would become a very messy place to be in very soon. :)