# Are Apps using iAd compatible with older iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, version, iad

Can I add the UIBannerViewDelegate protocol to my UIViewController subclass while remaining compatible with pre-iOS 4 devices?

This is NOT a duplicate, the question is specifically related to the delegate protocol.

Comment: Translation: *Can I add the `UIBannerViewDelegate` protocol to my `UIViewController` subclass while remaining compatible with pre-iOS 4 devices?*

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120/how-to-make-iphone-app-for-multiple-firmwares/3027213#3027213

Comment: Not Duplicate: it doesn't answer my question. This relates to the protocol as bbum says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you weak-link the iAd framework, you will encounter no issues with a controller class that conforms to the ADBannerViewDelegate protocol.  You will, of course, need to add the ADBannerView programmatically (if it exists on the running OS) or otherwise load a different Nib file for 3.x vs. 4.x.

Even though there is no ADBannerViewDelegate protocol in iPhone OS 3.x, I just tested and no errors are thrown for missing symbols if a class that conforms to it is loaded in that older OS.

Comment: Yeah, it works this way. You just need to check: "if (NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView"))". See more code details here: http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2010/07/what-ive-already-used-more-than-once.html