# pre-iOS 4 devices delegate protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, version, target

Can I add the UIBannerViewDelegate protocol to my UIViewController subclass while remaining compatible with pre-iOS 4 devices?

This is NOT a duplicate, the question is specifically related to the delegate protocol.

Comment: Edit your previous question to clarify it.  Don't create a new one.  [Are Apps using iAd compatible with older iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128457/are-apps-using-iad-compatible-with-older-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d try something like:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_4_0

@interface MYViewController <UIBannerViewDelegate, …>

#else

@interface MYViewController < … >

#endif
```

Remember to `#include <TargetConditionals.h>;`.

Edit: this question duped [Are Apps using iAd compatible with older iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128457) which has a more complete answer.