# iphone os 4 app is not working on ipod touch os 3+

Tags: iphone, ios4, universal, ipod-touch

after i complied my app on IOS4 my app stopped working on ipod touches. it is a first generation ipod touch, with os 3 on it. So i assume application for OS4 are not working on old ipodtouches ? but there was no warring from the app store and it is even listed for download for ipod touch too. any ideas ?

base SDK is iphone device 4 and development target is iphone os 3. i works on iphone's with os 3 but when i try it on my ipod touch with os 3.1.3 it crashed. and i am getting this error mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack. I added a break on main.m and the app crashes even before getting to first line in main.m .. the debug is ok it crashes when i try to run it on the device. it works fine in simulator.

One more thing, this is a universal app, and i am using uisplitview controller.. so i think when it runs on os 3 it breaks.. is there anyway to fix this ?

Comment: we need more information than this...did you try debugging? what gave you the error? etc.

Comment: Also, what was your deployment target?  Was it also set to 4.0?  Note that iOS 4.0 will run on 2nd and 3rd generation iPod touches, just not the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok!!! I assumed my main.m will do the job and point the right appdelegate  but apparently i still needed to check if the classes exist. so here is the answer

```
Class splitVCClass = NSClassFromString(@"UISplitViewController");
if (splitVCClass)
{
        //UISplitViewController* mySplitViewController = [[splitVCClass alloc] init];
    UISplitViewController* _splitViewController = [[splitVCClass alloc]init];
    [_splitViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_rootNavigationController,_navigationController,nil]];
}
```

happy ending.

Answer (score 0):

Apps built for iOS 4.0 will not run on devices with 3.0.  Note that in the App Store, there is a section under "Requirements:" that says "Requires iOS 4.0 or later." in cases like this.

Comment: They will if you set your Deployment Target to 3.0 as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120/).