# warning: iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture (current ARCHS = "armv7")

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

I want to limit my universal-build app to iPhone4 / iPad, and I've set `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to include "armv7", accordingly.  In the build settings I've set:

```
"Architectures" = "Optimized (armv7)"

"Valid Architectures" = "armv7"
```

But the Release and Distribution builds of my universal app are generating this warning:

*`warning: iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture (current ARCHS = "armv7")`*

Is this even a real problem?  Can I safely ignore the warning?  Why doesn't my debug build exhibit the same warning - the build config has the same settings?

I'm building with XCode 3.2.5, 4.2 SDK.

Similar to this question, but not quite:

["Warning: iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture" even with build config set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stay with arm7 only if you want, but if you want to limit to iPhone 4 / iPad it's because you have a good reason ? To limit to devices you need to use `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in your Info.plist, otherwise people with previous iPhone will find your app and it will not work.

PS: It's not easy to find a device capability for both iPad and iPhone, you can for example said that you want devices with a front facing camera but this will limit to iPhone 4 and iPad 2 (and not iPad 1)

Comment: Yes, I am setting armv7 in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.  Mainly I want to limit because the hardware we tested on was armv7-only, and the app is compute-intensive so we enjoy the armv7 speed.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. I set the **project settings** accordingly but was still getting the error when building the Release version. I had to edit the **Target settings** and found that 'Build Active Architecture Only' was checked for the Release configuration. Unchecking it resolved the warning. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Build Active Architecture only is really best used just for debug and simulator builds.

The iOS deployment target version is what determines the required architectures.  iOS 4.2 and earlier included support for armv6 processors; therefore Xcode wants you to build for that architecture for builds that might be distributed.

If you really don't want armv6 code, and understand that the app store will reject your app if it targets iOS 4.2 or earlier and does not have armv6, then I'd suggest just changing the "Architectures" setting in the target to armv7 only.