# Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version

Tags: iphone, installation, device

Using an itouch with 4.2.1 (8C148) and an iphone 4.2.1 (8C148) on XCode 3.2, showed this warning.  Tried installing Xcode SDK 4.0 (which looks really cool but ultra confusing) but iphone showing same thing in organiser?  Any thoughts?  Went from 11am to 6pm on this yesterday and know I've missed something really basic.  Any help very very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your Deployment target to 4.2. By default, it will usually attempt to target the latest version.

If you're in XCode 4, click on the Application Name at the top of your left navigation pane, which should take you to the project task settings. On the Info Tab, you'll see "iOS Deployment Target". Mine defaults to 4.3.

Comment: Oh right, I see it, ok will give it a go - thank you!  Should I be changing the base SDK to 4.2 also may I ask?  Sorry I'll have to reply as to if it installed later today as the device I'm testing on is my partners - just to make life that little bit easier lol

Comment: No need to change the Base SDK. XCode will handle that for you when you set the Deployment Target. The Base SDK may still say 4.3, but it will deploy code that is suited for 4.2.

Comment: Thats really great, thank you very much for helping, felt rather confused yesterday :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just answered [a similar question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885859/xcode-cannot-find-the-software-image-to-install-this-version). The particular message *"Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version"* ...is (as you have found) generally not the issue. A number of other things can prevent the app running from Xcode