# getting error "Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version" on deployment?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to configure iPad for testing and and following steps to make device ready for this. while in the way I am following this error as you can see in the Pic

"Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version"

Actually I attached the device with xCode and it started some installation after that it showed this error.

in ios program developer guide I read this line

**Download the iOS Disk Image (.dmg) from the iOS Dev Center for the Apple device you are using.**

is it due to this? please help

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you doing that causes this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the device is already set up for development. You don't need to restore your iPad to continue.

Do you have a valid provisioning profile set up?

Answer (score 0):

I just answered [a similar question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885859/xcode-cannot-find-the-software-image-to-install-this-version). The particular message *"Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version"* ...is generally not the issue. A number of other things can prevent the app running from Xcode