# 'Xcode could not find software image to install in this version' xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Does anybody know how to deal with **provisioning profile** in the **xcode 4.5 > organizer** where provisioning profile of the iPhone device that reads ***'Xcode could not find software image to install in this version'.***

I got the certificate and provisioning profile set up on Apple developer page even with a **green** light beside my iphone device it indicates that it is active but **'Xcode could not find software image to install in this version'.**

That message just means it can't restore my iPhone as it doesn't have the right thing downloaded. How do I get it right? I'm using iOS6  on my iPhone 4s.

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/xcode_device.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/xcode_device.png)
[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/xcode_device_restore.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/xcode_device_restore.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/8537034/1378694

Comment: Yes I saw that. That is dated December 2011. This question is for Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6. I think I've found a solution but I've another problem emerged out of it with a missing libCordova.a  As @Owen Hartnett says about "iPhone 4S, which uses armv7" so I don 't have to do anything with it. Different solution for December 2011 and this is October 2012 with xcode 4.5. Unfortunate, it  look like a duplicate provisioning profile but with different solutions for xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "Software Version" doesn't apply to a provisioning profile, but to the iOS software on your device.  Xcode just doesn't have the capability of restoring iOS 6 to your device now.  For your provisioning profiles, in the left side sidebar, click on "Provisioning Profiles" to deal with them.

Comment: Can you clarify - "For your provisioning profiles, in the left side sidebar". How do I click on "Provisioning Profiles" to deal with them"? There are three "Provisioning Profiles" on xcode > organiser.

Comment: Yes, they're grouped underneath the thing where they're located.  The ones in each device are under the device, for the mac that Xcode is running on, they're under Library.  Most of the time, all you have to do is drag a provisioning profile into Xcode, and it does the right thing.

Comment: If you're missing a provisioning profile, you'll get a message to that effect.  You can ignore the message that you're asking about, it won't affect your ability to code to your device.

Comment: It is the iTunes...that I've to back up on to my computer instead of  iCloud. Then its sorted after all this hassle!! Without instructions from Apple. IT'S SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

The message "*xcode cannot find the software image to install this version*" seen in the organiser window... This is just a notification rather than a problematic error.

If you want to eliminate this message anyway, I found I was able to do this by running restore within iTunes. Part of that process involves downloading some stuff, which I presume is the 'software image'.

But, as explained in [Technical Q&A QA1569](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1569/_index.html) "This message does not prevent you from using the device for development purposes. The only effect is the inability to reinstall the OS currently on the device using Xcode." ...and that has been my experience. Back in the main Xcode window you're still able to click 'run' and send the app to the device to run.

...and it will run assuming everything else is set-up OK, but there are various other gotchas related to Xcode 4.2 and v4 devices:

- As mentioned by Overbeeke you should ensure the 'deployment target'
  of your project is set down to the desired version (the minimum
  version of the devices you want to support) Additionally I would
  point out that the 'SDK version' should normally remain set to the
  latest (it's whatever SDK Xcode on your machine is using)
- As mentioned by Kenneth Lam, in the new Xcode you need to frig around
  with "armv6/armv7" settings if you want to support earlier models of
  iPhone. Follow [these instructions to add the right "Architecture"
  armv6 setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7687527/338265). Additionally I would point out (as [per this answer
  further down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833556/338265)) that there is a setting called "Required device
  capabilities" from which you need to remove 'armv7'. This is in your
  app's plist file.

I'm saying all this like I'm an expert, but I still can't get it to work on a v3.1.3 device :-)

Comment: I saw this...post as above on Stackover. I find it so conflicting with different advices for example "armv6/armv7" settings as I'm using iPhone4s with iOS6 (upgraded from Apple site). Does "armv6/armv7" settings still apply on Xcode 4.5 and iOS6? I'm not sure. Otherwise, It is a good advice - only if you know what you're looking for the solution.

Comment: You have an iPhone 4S, which uses armv7.  You don't have to change the default settings for architecture.

Comment: Thanks Owen. Just as well I didn't change the default settings for architecture.