# getting error “Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version” on deployment after updating ios and xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

I keep getting the error:

“Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version” on deployment?

I upgaded my iPhone to version 6.1.3 and also recently updated xcode to the lastest as well. Before doing this, I could deploy my apps to my phone, but now my apps won't deploy to my device.

Do I have to go and make another provisioning profile and all that stuff again? (I did it all a couple of months ago and got everything working when I was still on iOS 5).

Thx,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade the version of your Xcode to 4.6 in order to use your iOS 6.1.3 device for testing & deployment purposes.

The latest version of Xcode is 4.6.1. You can update it using Appstore App.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue. Eventually I found refreshing my provisioning profiles (in Organiser, select devices, in Library select Provisioning Profiles (top left) and click on refresh (bottom right). Then my devices accurately reflected my provisioning profiles and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

The message "xcode cannot find the software image to install this version" seen in the organiser window... This is just a notification rather than a problematic error.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537034/736384

So, if it is a update problem, **Rajan**'s answer should solve it, if not:

That message has nothing to do with the problem that you can not compile.  When you want to compile, didn't Xcode show any message error?

Anyway you could **try restarting Xcode** (quit **iTunes** first if it's running).