# ios6.1.3 can't be supported by xcode 4.5.2

Tags: xcode4.5, ios6.1

My ipad2 has beed upgraded to ios6.1.3, and then the Xcode can't recognize this device .
When updating the xcode to 4.5.2,this problem still exists.
So how can I resolve this issue,Please help me.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611973/getting-error-xcode-cannot-find-the-software-image-to-install-this-version-on

Answer (score 2):

That's because Xcode 4.5.2 is also outdated. Try [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) link to Xcode 4.6.2