# Why iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1.3 is not connecting with xcode 4.5 for testing purposes?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

I am trying to connect my new iphone 4 with ios 6.1.3 with xcode 4.5 for testing my app built on ios 6.It is showing xcode does not support the device with this ios in the organizer window of xcode.
I have already installed the provisioning profile for testing on the phone.

Comment: You need Xcode 4.6.x to use iOS 6.1.x.

Comment: is it necessary to upgrade the xcode to achieve this? Can it  be possible without upgrading the xcode ?

Comment: ok i will download the new xcode to check it ,thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting error “Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version” on deployment after updating ios and xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611973/getting-error-xcode-cannot-find-the-software-image-to-install-this-version-on)

Answer (score 2):

Use XCode 4.6.x for Debuging of OS version iOS 6.1 or later.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the deployment target as 6.1 for your project.. then run it into the iphone 4 with iOS version of 6.1.3. surely it will run.. If you dont have 6.1 deployment target you have to upgrade your xcode with 6.1

Comment: Xcode 4.5 doesn't have iOS 6.1. That is why he is being told to upgrade to Xcode 4.6.