# Xcode 4.5 Doesn't Recognize My Device iphone 5 (6.1.3)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

I am using Xcode 4.5. When I plug my device in, it is not showing up on run button, and I have a message that it can't run using the selected device.. The Problem is this two days to go its working very well  and i am installed many application before with this  xcode 4.5 and iphone 5 (6.1.3) Dont know whats going on today Any idea Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check your targeted iOS sdk in XCode. Also check whether you added this device for development

Comment: restart your device...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611973/getting-error-xcode-cannot-find-the-software-image-to-install-this-version-on

Answer (score 2):

Open your Xcode organizer (Shift+Cmd+2), go to Devices tab, select your device in the list and press "Use for development" button

Answer (score 1):

Check that your deployment target is set low enough for your device OS.

Comment: He's running iOS 6.1.3.

Comment: As low as what exactly?

Comment: i Updated my Iphone ios 6.1.3 to 6.1.4 and its working on  xcode 4.5  cheers

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.5 supports till iOS 6.0 for iOS 6.1.3 you need to upgrade your Xcode to 4.6.0 version.

Comment: Likely because XCode 4.5 supports iOS 6+ and iPhone 5.

Comment: 6.1.3 won't be supported in XCode 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

I would venture that your device isn't included in the provisioning profile you're trying to compile the code with. Check organizer and see if your device has your target provisioning profile listed. If it does, unplug the iPhone, restart XCode and the phone and try again.

EDIT
@Armaan Stranger also brings up a good point about XCode 4.5 and iOS 6.1.3 however I'm a bit confused as to how you had it working previously.

Comment: i Updated my Iphone ios 6.1.3 to 6.1.4 and its working on xcode 4.5 cheers

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for actually reporting back out :)