# iPhone apps with a deployment target lower than 4.3 should include an armv6 architecture

Tags: xcode, xcode4, warnings, build-settings

I have a problem :-( When I build my application for release XCode shows a warning saying:

```
iPhone apps with a deployment target lower than 4.3 should include an armv6 architecture (current IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = "3.0", ARCHS = "armv7").
```

But how can I set `armv6` in my build settings? I'm using `XCode 4.2` and here's my build settings:

[image]

[image]

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I haven't used the version, but the current Xcode won't support signing for iOS 2.0 , so when iOS 5 comes out,  3.0 might have the same issue of not being supported

This is from http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=3050 (This site has helped me resolve so many errors, so props to Mike D.)

> 1. In Xcode navigate to Build Settings and find Architectures group (it’s on the top, so hard to miss). Add armv6 to Architectures line. It should contain armv6, armv7 or Standard (armv6 armv7)
> 2. Set Base SDK to Latest iOS (currently set to iOS …)
> 3. Uncheck Build Active Architecture Only or set it to NO.
> 4. Valid Architectures must show armv6 armv7
>      When your project uses your own dependent libraries, build them with the same (correct) configuration.

Comment: Oh, maybe you're right :-). But in the meantime is it possible to add armv6?

Comment: After some research, I found a useful blog post that detailed how to fix this. It's now in my answer

Comment: Wanted to add that for the Architecture setting, "armv6 armv7" might not work.  For my project, it only worked when I left the old value, and added armv6, resulting in: "armv6 $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)"

Comment: Interesting. Well Xcode does define $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) to be armv7 (as seen in the screenshot from the question), so the same principle is behind it. See what works for you, brack's method seem to work for him.

Comment: If you want a more detailed/screenshot-filled version of what you need to do, its available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config/7687527#7687527

Comment: Changing Architectures to "armv6 armv7" worked for me in xcode 4.2

Comment: To be completely clear for newbies: As Sum says in comments, Xcode has a variable for the current architecture.  In the drop-down on the major "Architectures" category, select the drop down, and in my case armv6 is no longer available in the list (pre-iOS 5).  So I selected other, then the plus button, and added the literal string "armv6" to the list, then build.  That takes care of that!