# Objective C: Missing architecture

Tags: objective-c, ios, architecture

When I go to validate my app, I get the error
`executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architectures must be present: armv6`

I'm using Xcode 4.2 and the iOS5 SDK and deploying to 3.2. This never happened before I updated the SDK.

I'm also getting several warnings coming up when I build for archiving:

```
Check dependencies

[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file/Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/charset.alias
[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/libcurl.la
[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/libgcrypt.la
[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file  /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/libgpg-error.la
[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/libsasl2.la
[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/libssh2.la
[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/libcrypto.pc
 [WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/libssh2.pc
 [WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/libssl.pc
 [WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/openssl.pc
 [WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/zlib.pc
 [BWARN]warning: iPhone apps with a deployment target lower than 4.3 should include an armv6 architecture (current IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = "3.2", ARCHS = "armv7").

Ld "/Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/Math Buddy" normal armv7
cd "/Volumes/iOS Development/Apps/Math Buddy"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 3.2
setenv PATH "/Developer-4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer-4.2/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer-4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer-4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -L/Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos "-L[sdk=iphonesimulator3.2][arch=*]" -L= -L/Volumes/iOS -LDevelopment/Apps/Math -LBuddy/../iPhoneSimulator-3.2/lib "-L[sdk=iphoneos3.2][arch=*]" -L= -L/Volumes/iOS -LDevelopment/Apps/Math -LBuddy/../iPhoneOS-3.2/lib "-L/Volumes/iOS Development/Apps/Math Buddy/iPhoneOS-3.2/lib" "-L/Volumes/iOS Development/Apps/Math Buddy/iPhoneSimulator-3.2/lib" -F/Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos -filelist "/Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Intermediates/Math Buddy.build/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Math Buddy.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=3.2 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lcrypto -lcurl -letpan -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lsasl2 -lssh2 -lssl -lz -lcrypto -lcurl -letpan -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lsasl2 -lssh2 -lssl -lz -o "/Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Math_Buddy-cywtminuxpdkhkanmtqkswygozhr/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/Math Buddy.app/Math Buddy"
```

Comment: Be aware that iOS 5 is still under NDA and you are not allowed to talk about it except on the apple developers forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on another stack question. All I had to do was add an array entry for `Required device capabilities` 
["Warning: iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture" even with build config set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config-s/6833556#6833556)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the same configuration and in Architectures is says: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) armv6. With this and target 3.2 I dont get any warning. Check your architectures is they are the same. So it seems that armv6 must be present. Just go to your Target -> Build Settings -> Architecture. Doublie-click -> others and add armv6, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

project -> edit project settings -> in build tab search with "active" then unselect build active arch only

If you uncheck "Build Active Architecture Only", then it will build all the valid architectures.

originally taken from [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config-s)