# warning: iPad only apps should not include an armv6 architecture (current ARCHS = "armv6 armv7")

Tags: ios, armv6

I am submitting an app and i am getting an warning "warning: iPad only apps should not include an armv6 architecture (current ARCHS = "armv6 armv7")." please advice how to remove this warning?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your the Architectures in you build settings, see this SO question: [Warning iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture even with build config set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config-s) which is the opposite of your warning.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, go to **Project** → **Build Settings** → **Architectures**.

Then, change your architecture to Standard (armv7).