# XCode 4.2 compiling for iPhone 3g (armv6)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, armv7, armv6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture even with build config set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config-s)

I've upgraded to XCode 4.2 in order to target iOS 5 devices (As per Apple's instructions) I'm attempting to release a version of an App that targets both armv6 and armv7 (Or at the very least armv6). When I've built the app and archived it ready for submitting to apple I've clicked verify in the new Organiser submitting screen and get told: "iPhone/iPod Touch application is missing a required architecture: at least one of the following architectures must be present: armv6"

The project settings for Architectures won't allow me to choose anything other than Standard(armv7) do I have any way to compile this app for 3g iPhones? Or do I have to restrict the app to newer models / downgrade to an earlier XCode?

---

Just in case this question isn't closed as a duplicate, the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config-s/7687527#7687527)

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config-s/7687527#7687527)

Comment: Thanks I had seen the question, but didn't scroll further than the accepted answer, which didn't help. Will learn to read answers more carefully from now...