# How to put my app in a iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

I am using Xcode 4.2 to develop my apps. My current ongoing project is set to run on ios4.2, but i only have a iPhone 3G (not 'S') to test my app. The problem is that when i try to run my app in my device, xcode says it was compiled and running on device but the app doenst even install in my iPhone.

I have read on other posts that i have to change the armvX configuration, so how do I do that in order for my app to run in a iPhone 3G?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of iOS are you running on the 3G? Is it 4.2 or higher?

Comment: The 3G can only be upgraded until iOS 4.2.1 - anything beyond that won't be installable on your device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture even with build config set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hardware issue rather than an iOS version issue.

In the Architectures section of your build configuration it probably just says armv7.

You need it so have two entries, armv6 and armv7. Select Other from the architectures menu then delete the default then add two new entries, one that just says armv6, on that just says armv7.

This creates a fat binary (essentially two binaries) which will contain the v6 code the 3G needs.

Comment: Is that the only place that i have to do this change? i read somewhere that i also have to change this in the plist, is it correct?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I had this happen to me on an app store submission and adding in the build properties is all I had to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have my Mac in front of me but i believe in the Target settings for the project
(click on the project in Xcode and under targets select your project name)

In the settings there you will see it more then liekly saying armv7 change to a lower number armv and i believe it will work.

though i cant be sure

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the project view. (Short cut key: Command-1)
2. Select the project to see its summary.
3. Under iOS Application Target, there should be a Deployment Target.
4. Select the version 3.1.3 or whatever the desired minimum version.

Comment: dude, thats not the problem.. my iphone is on 4.3 and my deployment target is 4.2. That was no my question!