# making app work for ios 3.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am about to upload my very first app and I changed the deployment target 30 ios 3.0 and I am getting a warning that I have no idea what to with. If anyone could help me out, it would be much appreciated since I am basically done! (I hope). Its talking about some arv6 architectures and I don't know what that means.

Thanks!

> [BWARN]warning: iPhone apps with a deployment target lower than 4.3
>   should include an armv6 architecture (current
>   IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = "3.0", ARCHS = "armv7").
>
> warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a
>   required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s)
>   must be present: armv6 (-19033)

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but what I would do is search the build settings for ARCHS and VALID_ARCHS, and try to add armv6 to both.

Comment: check this link : > http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=84D9F80D0F2689E25806D53&status=&searchInput=search...&sortColumn=FT.id&sortUpDown=DESC&currentPage=9&doViews=1

Answer (score 1):

In your project -> build settings -> architectures, try adding an arm6 architecture

See this answer, it has a step by step process of how to add an architecture
["Warning: iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture" even with build config set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Better question - why do you feel you need to support iOS3.x?

At this point you should switch to ARC and support only 4.x devices or greater, unless there is an absolutely compelling need.  Remember that percentage wise only a tiny number of devices at this point are restricted to iOS3.