# Solution to "required architectures" using Required Device Capabilities in info.plist in Xcode 4.2 prevents upgrade path

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

Upgrading my year-old iPhone project to Xcode 4.2, I ran in to the following much discussed validation error in the Organizer.

```
iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6.
```

Following the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config/7687527#7687527), using both the project/target Architectures settings AND the info.plist "Required device capabilities" key, I was able to resolve the error.  HOWEVER, now I get the following validation error in the Organizer.

```
This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application from running on devices that were supported by a previous version.
```

Since I am setting the capabilities to both armv6 and armv7, it should work on all devices (yes?). The key was not present in the previous version of my info.plist file, so perhaps the fact that it has been added is triggering the second validation error.

Is this actually a mistake of the validator within the Organizer (iTunes Connect)?  Or is there some other way of getting around the problem?