# App is not installing only in 4s device?

Tags: iphone

App is not installing in 4s device but its installing in 3g and others.How can I solve this? and may I know the reason for this.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

You must add the armv6 architecture. To see how this is done:

["Warning: iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture" even with build config set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the UDID of the device is added to your provisioning profile or not?

Comment: Hi Mathew Varghese, I missed to include an armv6 architecture Now its working.Thanks....