# xcode validation error : application executable is missing a required architecture

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

our clients also reported same error that discussed here:[CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config) . None of the solution in that fixed my problem…may be I did in wrong place... ……………..

Error : iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least on of the following architexture(s) must be present: armv6 …………

Help me to set right settings in plist and Xcode target. OS supported iOS 4.3 and above and device both iPhone/iPad/iPod.

Here is sample Xcode project: http://po.st/0fc5AU

Please updated this sample and send me. I tried a lot but confused with all solution...again reported same bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
 armv6 armv7
```

to the Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings of your target.

PS: if you're using cocos2d v2.x this won't work, it doesn't work with armv6 devices since they only support OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: thanks for the reply sir, YES, now using cocos2d v2.0. After adding armv6 armv7 getting too many errors. As u told its not work with armv6, means all project with cocos2d v2.0 not support 3G and below device? How can I support 2G device with cocos2d v2.0?

Comment: You can't support iphone 2G with cocos2d v2.0. Cocos2D v2.0 is build upon OpenGL ES 2.0 and the iphone 2G only works with OpenGL ES 1.1. For more info please check the documentation: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:migrate_to_v2.0