# Validating app, application is missing Architecture armv7

Tags: objective-c, architecture, armv7, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

When I'm updating my first iOS app , I have 2 problems validating them,

```
*iPhone/iPod Touch:application executable is missing a required architecture. 
At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7

*Unable to extract entitlements from application: (null)
```

The Info.plist and build settings are all the defaults, the only thing I changed is the code signing Identity debug and release to my distribution provisioning profile, with the app ID and Bundle Id identically.

Answer (score 76):

This happened to me when i had my iphone 5 connected and built my archive.  when i disconnected my iPhone and built my archive, it went through fine.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time. I got similar issue but with armv7s error: "This bundle is invalid. Apps that include an armv7s architecture are required to include an armv7 architecture". Was wondering why. Unplugging my iPhone 5 from USB port fixed this weird issue.

Comment: I can't even believe this haha! But it worked! Unplugged my phone, went right past validation! +1

Comment: Yet another ridiculous time-wasting problem!  Thanks, I was tearing my hair out for a bit there.....

Comment: Oh My GOD! it is even possible?

Comment: it's not magic, it's the "Build Active Architecture Only" setting in your project. for your distribution config you'll want to set this to "NO", see an old but good one: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/21/xcode-build-active-architecture-only.html

Comment: iPad Air also seems to cause problems. I had to disconnect both iPhone 5 and iPad Air.

Comment: LOL... can't believe it =)))

Comment: BOTH answers are correct. When you have a phone plugged in, that phone's architecture is the ACTIVE ARCHITECTURE, so you need to unplug the phone (faster but annoying) or change the settings (permanent)

Answer (score 23):

Make sure 'Build Active Architectures' is set to No in BOTH the project and target settings too as well as the answers here ["Warning: iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture" even with build config set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-conf)

Comment: @chadbag this comment made my day, thanks :)
and Thiago, please accept this answer

Answer (score 4):

Now I resolved the problem, that was a very simple problem, it was with my executable name.

My target have an invalid character (+) then, when i upload my app it shows a problem (this bundle is invalid , the executable name can not contain this characters ....) then i changed the executable name from ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} to Chemistry, but the registered name of my app is Chemistry++.

And then the validate show others problems, which has been produced by changing this.

For resolving the problem I click on the project > target two times and changed the name, with no invalid characters ( * . , + {} () ) , all the problems disappeared.

Then it upload successfully.

(When I change the Info.plist executable name, for other name, it creates incompatibility, so don't to it and make it defaults ( ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ), if you change, it creates other problems.)

Waiting for apple review!!!

Comment: For some reason when you reuse an old project to create a new app, changing the executable file name (in info plist) causes these issues. This was the case for me and all the other answers, like valid architecture, target ios, etc, were all correct.

Answer (score 4):

Confirmed.  I just unplugged my iPhone 5s and re-archived the app.  It worked flawlessly.

Welp, I'll never get those 40 minutes of my life back.

Answer (score 3):

I was connected with **iPhone 5s and i got this error** while validating my app

[image]

Setting **"Build Active Architecture Only"** to **NO** for  **targets and project** resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO for all your targets, libraries and frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as I unplugged my iPad the warning went away and was able to compile and upload to app store.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there is no comma after armv7.

When I set the Architectures in the target's settings I wrote:

```
armv7, armv7s
```

It looked okay, but when I clicked on "other" to edit it, I realised it was set to:

```
armv7,
armv7s
```

Removing the comma (,) solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to Validate my (iPad-only) app I was trying to submit to the app store, I got three errors:

**1.  iPad: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7.**

Actually, I had armv7 and armv7s in all of my architecture settings, and, yes, I did have "Build Active Architecture Only" set to "No".

What fixed it for me was to manually remove armv7s from this list, leaving **just** armv7.  *Only then* did this error disappear.

So much for "at least one of the architectures must be armv7"

**2. Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.**

Huh ? 
Previously, I had been building this iPad app using an Enterprise License for Ad-Hoc distribution within our company.  Now, I was trying to get it to build using a Developer License, so I could deploy it to the App Store.

To fix this issue, I needed to:

- click on my project in the lefthand window
- select the project name (under Targets) in the middle window
- select the Build Settings tab
- just below the row tabs, select the "Basic" and "Combined" options.
- Now, under Code-Signing Identity, I needed to make sure I'd chosen a
  Code-Signing relating to my Apple Developer account, rather than the
  Enterprise account, and which was specifically for that project.

**3.  Unable to extract entitlements from application: (null)**

Huh ?!

Remember the good old days when an application just had a name ?  With XCode, your app has a bundle name, Product Name, Executable Name and a Bundle Display Name.

Several StackOverflow users have noted this, and pointed you in the direction of Apple's documentation, to explain the differences... but good luck with that.

For me, to fix this issue, I simply needed to make sure the Executable Name and Bundle Name (in the ***-Info.plist file) were identical, and also matched the Product Name.

Frustratingly, the Product Name is hidden away under the tab mentioned in Part 2 above, i.e. select the Build Settings tab, then select "Basic" and "Combined" in the header bar.

I hope this is useful to other developers.  This was all done using XCode 4.6.3, so will no doubt be out of date next month when iOS 7 and XCode 5 comes along.  By then, your app will probably also need a Nickname and MiddleName.  Who knows?

Mike

www.MikesKnowledgeBase.com

Comment: This was the solution for me. I had the *EXACT* same issue. My client was using the same code for multiple apps by changing the name. I had to change the app name (Product Name) under Build Settings as described in 3. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I was wondering whether it was just my bad luck, stumbling from one XCode issue to the next!  I'm glad my issues and solutions were useful to you !

Comment: It's just that sometimes clients was to use the same codebase to re-skin it and make a new app. This is what caused the problem for me. The code which I received from my client was reskined by some other developer and I had to upload to the AppStore which is when I encountered this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check target and project settings and set "Build Active Arch Only" to NO.

Answer (score 0):

it says missing a required architecture
try this

1. Go to **Targets** "your project"
2. Go to **Build Settings**
3. See if there is **armv7** in the **Architectures**
4. if not, then set **Architectures** to **armv7**
5. clean and build.

If there is **armv7** already, then something must be wrong.

hope it helps!

Comment: I already have armv7 to the Archs, and I have put armv7, standard(armv7), and armv7 armv6, and nothing works, the defaults is standard(armv7)

Comment: No. It's because some of the 4.5 beta user have some similar issues about Architectures / armv7. New Xcode version 4.5 is released, update it and let me know if there is still a problem

Comment: now I updated my Xcode and the problem persists, with the armv7 architecture. I sent a technical support to apple, because I don't find any solution anywhere. And when I updated other problem appeared, it's like codesign validation, but I revised the codesign thousands of times and the problem persists. If you have any solution PLEASE HELP.

Comment: basically i don't have any ideas right now what might be wrong, but it's annoying that xcode have so many problems that needs to be fixed.

Comment: As I've mentioned above - it's also worth changing the Architectures so that *just* Armv7 is listed (nothing else).  That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue, and it got resolved..

It turned out, that i've different Bundle/Executable name than the project name.

Go to Project > double click Target

Rename it to the Bundle/Executable name, then build for Release/iOS Device

and the Application loader will accept your App.

Answer (score 0):

Damned... this was a typo for me. When setting the architectures, I put a comma at the end of the first entry (armv7)... so that it was considered as invalid and ignored. removing this extra character has freed any problem...

Never forget to check your typo!