# Xcode 5.1:error for architecture x86_64 Facebook ios sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

i have 4 errors and the project is not compiling.

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
```

I have the facebook ios sdk 3.13.1

What are the consequences if I put **$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5.1 build opencv failed on 64 bit simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446060/xcode-5-1-build-opencv-failed-on-64-bit-simulator) (Different framework but same problem).  The consequence is that, like this library, your app will not contain a 64-bit slice.  That's OK though, for now, since arm64 is backwards compatible with armv7s.

Comment: in facebook ios sdk 3.8 say:
"This version also supports 64 bit applications and can be linked to by applications that target the arm64 architecture"
so Do not the library contain 64-bits?

Comment: The linker says otherwise.  Either that or you are accidentally using another version.

Answer (score 4):

Build phases -> "Link Binary with Libraries" -> + (add) -> "Add Other" -> point to the location of FacebookSDk.framework

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't for a Facebook application, I believe it is the same issue. I found this task to be difficult myself so I made a video explaining how to remove the arm64 from the valid architectures. Hope it helps!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-pJLRy4rVk&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: Thanks for information, the problem was that the project called for the old facebook sdk, moving the project to another path resolved the problem for my.

Comment: That makes sense because SDK takes advantage of the 64bit processor.

Comment: But removing arm64 will cause a failure in uploading to App store, it causes (Missing 64-bit support) error. How to solve this issue and keep old facebook sdk?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the fix in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546466/fbsdkloginmanager-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-linker-command-fa) stackoverflow post thread

**"The current instructions on Facebook's SDK Getting Started page forget to mention this. In version < 4 of the SDK, there was just one file to drag in to your project."**

In my case i have to include `FBSDKShareKit.framework`to build successfully.