# App fails validation

Tags: ios, xcode

Why did I get this error? I have validated the app four times but I get the same result every time.

[image: error window]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating app, application is missing Architecture armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487689/validating-app-application-is-missing-architecture-armv7)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378484/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload-appname-app-app-name-dec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Bundle Identifier.  Make sure your bundle identifier is correct.  If that doesn't work I would double check that all your settings are correct in "Build Settings".  For some reason when I added iCloud to my app, I altered my code signing settings.