# ERROR ITMS-9000 : invalid bundle. the bundle at xyz.app does not contain bundle executable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, itunes-store

I'm trying to submit app to app store. I'm getting this error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000 : invalid bundle. the bundle at xyz.app does not contain bundle executable.

Everything is correct: `bundle ID`, `certificate`, `provision profile` all are the same. But still giving me the error above.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your device is not connected to your computer. And then build your archive. Such was the case here: [Validating app, application is missing Architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487689/validating-app-application-is-missing-architecture-armv7)

Answer (score 1):

The same issue was also reported here: [Apple iTunes Connect App submission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764689/apple-itunes-connect-app-submission-error)

I have also experienced this but have not resolved it yet![enter image description here][1]

Am building for architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s

Comment: hello , Thanks for submitting same question with image. I'm building with same architecture don't know why I'm still getting that error

Comment: I left an answer on the other question that might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are building for `arm64 armv7 armv7s`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Build Setting->Architectures->Build Architectures->Yes

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 7.1.1 & latest iOS is 9.1

You need to change:

- Build Active Architecture Only to NO (include debug & release).
- Valid Architectures arm64, arm7, arm7s