# Apple iTunes Connect App submission error

Tags: ios, iphone

Apple iTunes Submission Error : Unable to process application at this time due to following error: bundle 'xyz.app' is missing a bundle executable.

Certificates and Profile : **Checked**

[image]

Comment: This is something new from Apple (yay!) I got this error while submitting a previously successfully submitted binary. That is, a binary that validated with no errors on August 28, 2014 now fails with this error on September 10, 2014.

Comment: It seams apple is updating their system. I used latest xcode version to upload build and BANNG.. submited successfully.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely happening due to the use of a "fake framework" (either the one from https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework or variations of this design). Some libraries and packages had their resources bundled together as a "framework" to make the inclusion of headers, nibs, images and localizable strings easier for host projects. However, those frameworks were actually a mutant bundle and don't meet the definition/structure that Apple is enforcing now that they've added Cocoa Touch Frameworks.

Some solutions:

- Split the "fake framework" into a separate .a binary, resource bundle and set of headers. I'd recommend using Cocoapods to package them up so that anyone trying to incorporate the library/bundle/headers doesn't have to deal with manual inclusion at multiple steps. You can still lipo together multiple .a files that are targeting the architectures for devices/simulators to create a universal binary and all will work fine.
- Switch to using a Cocoa Touch Framework (though, these appear to only work for deployment target 8.0) and embed the binary into the app. If you go this route, you'll need to also make a separate bundle for your resources because your framework now contains a binary (and thus, adding it as a "resource" package is going to cause you to have multiple binaries in your app when you package it and it'll get rejected from the app store). See here for some info on creating an iOS resource bundle: http://jaym2503.blogspot.ro/2014/03/how-to-create-resource-bundle-in-ios.html . There are some other nuances and gotchas with this approach (such as if you lipo together the simulator/device binaries in the framework and then embed the framework, you'll get rejected from the app store for having a binary embedded that includes architectures for the simulator). Unfortunately, as of now there isn't much documentation from Apple on how to use these frameworks, so it's a lonely road.

I'd personally recommend the Cocoapod route.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are building for `arm64 armv7 armv7s`

Comment: @Thanks Hannes, and yes i was building for arm64,armv7 and armv7s at that time. i guess that was probably issue with apple server.