# Xcode submission error: Invalid Bundle Structure

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

I'm trying to submit an app to the App Store but app loader won't get past validation because of a particular error I've never seen before. [image: Odd error]

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Are you building with the latest Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I am building with the latest - 6.1.1.

Comment: @TonyFriz i have get this error while app submission any idea about it `ERROR ITMS-90207: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'example.app' does not contain a bundle executable`.

Comment: @ilesh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759561/error-itms-9000-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-xyz-app-doesn-not-contain-bundle