# bundle invalid. Key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Contains 'Item 0'. With MinimumVersion 4.3

Tags: ios, itunes, info.plist

I have added `Item 0` value at `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` at `Info.plist`. But while uploading to iTunes, getting the following errors

> The bundle is invalid. The Key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains
>   value 'Item 0' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value
>   of '4.3'

I have added this, following the resource # ["Warning: iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture" even with build config set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config) (from @ustinxreese answer).

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to simply remove both (ARM7 and ARM6) from the required capabilities?

Comment: @Till, Yes it worked. +1 for comment. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Into the *info.plist* file, remove "Item 0" in "Required background models" and "Required device  capabilities"

Answer (score 0):

Remove both, ARM6 and ARM7 from the Required Capabilities within your info.plist.