# App crashing immediately after start

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ios-provisioning

EDIT: My problem was because the plist file was corrupted . So if you have the same issue, probably is because of something in you plist file.

SO i have this app and everything worked just fine until i updated my device to IOS 6. After that i couldn't install the app on the device . The app worked just fine on IOS 5.0 simulator and IOS 6.0 simulator . When i try to build it for device , the splash screen appears for two second and then the app closes . In Xcode i receive this error :

```
timed out waiting for app to launch
```

I searched the web and it said that it is a AdHoc provisioning problem but my provisioning profiles are in order . I even changed the app id and deleted the old provisioning and i got the same error .

In the device console i receive this weird error :

```
Oct 15 23:48:23 iPad2-3G backboardd[51] <Warning>: Launch Services: Registered unknown app identifier InvoiceAppDev
��Oct 15 23:48:23 iPad2-3G backboardd[51] <Warning>: Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier InvoiceAppDev
Oct 15 23:48:23 iPad2-3G backboardd[51] <Warning>: Can't create application "InvoiceAppDev" without a bundle path
Oct 15 23:48:44 iPad2-3G mobile_house_arrest[200] <Error>: Max open files: 78
��Oct 15 23:48:44 iPad2-3G installd[30] <Error>: 0x2ff81000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/InvoiceApp.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
Oct 15 23:48:44 iPad2-3G installd[30] <Error>: 0x2ff81000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app InvoiceAppDev
��Oct 15 23:48:44 iPad2-3G installd[30] <Error>: Oct 15 23:48:44  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Oct 15 23:48:45 iPad2-3G installd[30] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
��Oct 15 23:48:45 iPad2-3G installd[30] <Error>: entitlement 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
```

I don't have any clue what happened . Does anybody has any idea why this happened ?

Comment: after the app fails, does it show on the device?  You might also try deleting the app from the device and then try again?

Comment: reboot everything. device and computer. set breakpoint for exceptions. delete and reinstall from clean build.  the console messages aren't familiar, but they sure do look to be a provisioning issue.

Comment: and then there's the classic arm6 problem wherein you're not building the app for the phone's architecture because settings have changed out from under you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198676/warning-iphone-apps-should-include-an-armv6-architecture-even-with-build-config

Comment: i am facing the same problem can anyone give proper solution for how to fix it.

Comment: for me it was because of the .plist file . I replaced it with an old version that i had and everything worked fine .

Comment: Are you using a development provisioning profile?

Comment: Can you show us full log file contents?

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same error caused by the accidental entry of the following blank field in app.plist:

```
+   <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
+   <string></string>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why this happens ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same symptoms.  Believe it or not, I changed my target code signing from distribution to developer and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nycynik - that solved the problem.
In xcode open the the "Organizer", choose the device (ex. iPhone), select "Application" and delete the previous Version of the 
App. Than run again.

Comment: Or just hold the app's button down until it jiggles, then press the X that appears.