# Why i need versioning in my IPhone apps?

Tags: iphone

I don't understand, why i need versioning in my IPhone apps.Could anyone explain.

Comment: What makes you think you do?  I have no idea.

Comment: Please provide a link to the page that tells you you need versioning.  Versioning could mean about 5 different things to users here, so you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: Do you mean 1) a version number 2) multiple versions 3) version controlled source code 4) version controlled application data 5) support for multiple iOS versions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Make iPhone App compatible with multiple SDK (firmware) versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120/how-to-make-iphone-app-compatible-with-multiple-sdk-firmware-versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple uses the version number when you submit an update to your app. If the update you submit does not have a version number greater than the currently shipping app, then Apple will not accept the update.

That is the only technical reason.

There are other reasons:

- it gives you a way to track issues against different releases
- it allows users to know whether they are up to date
  Etc

If course if you are never going to update your app then you can just set the version to 1.0 and forget about it...

Comment: Thanks Jasarien... but i have another doubt this versioning, doesn't mean to "support for multiple iOS versions".

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to support different versions - you can just choose one (probably the latest) and just develop for that. However, it will limit the number of devices that can run your application.

Read the accepted answer to this question (the one with the green tick next to it) for information about supporting different versions of iOS :

[How To Make iPhone App compatible with multiple SDK (firmware) versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120/how-to-make-iphone-app-compatible-with-multiple-sdk-firmware-versions)