# ios SDK 3.X download

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

I develop an application with XCode 4, and the SDK used for compilation is IOS 4.3.

Now I would like to use ios SDK 3 to supply my application for iPhone 3 users.

But I don't find where download ios SDK 3.0. On apple site (http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.9.3.3.1) I only see version 4.

Is there a reason why Apple don't allow ios SDK 3 download ?

Where can I find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build with the latest SDK4 and target IOS3 devices.

[How To Make iPhone App compatible with multiple SDK (firmware) versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120/how-to-make-iphone-app-compatible-with-multiple-sdk-firmware-versions/3027213#3027213)