# Is it possible to run App in all iPad Versions?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an application for both iPhone and iPad, and i build the app with the deployment target of iOS 5.1, now i confused whether the Application will run in all version of iPad. Sorry for this newbie question, since i am new to development. Please help me with your valuable solutions.

Comment: you should refer this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027120/how-to-make-iphone-app-compatible-with-multiple-sdk-firmware-versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an iOS 5.1 target, yes. (It will run on all iPads having iOS 5.1 *or later*).

But be aware that iOS 6 will no longer be supported on the first-gen iPad, and that the first-gen iPad has a lot less memory than the later models, which you may need to take into account if your app is "heavy".

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful and helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your app runs on iOS 5.1, it will run on any device that runs on iOS 5.1, whether it is iPad or iPhone.